# Laravel: Database - More "log column"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add some other columns next to the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, for example:

- `deleted_at`
- `creator`
- `updater`
- `deleter`

The last three should be contain `user.id`.

What is the better method?

- A. place it in the `migration`
- B. Edit the `Blueprint` class?

Comment: Do you want it for all of your migrations?

Comment: @SazzadurRahman yes, and for all of my projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly editing Laravel's core `Blueprint` class you should extend it and add functionality according to your specific needs. Here is an example how you can do this.

Create a `CustomBlueprint` class in `database` directory that extends core `Blueprint` class, which contains definitions of your custom columns.

```
<?php

namespace Database;

class CustomBlueprint extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint
{

    public function customColumns() {
        $this->integer('creator')->nullable();
        $this->integer('updater')->nullable();
        $this->integer('deleter')->nullable();
    }
}
```

After creating the custom blueprint run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Then create your migrations, such as

```
php artisan make:migration create_tests_table
```

In your migration file use `customColumns` method like this

```
<?php

use Database\CustomBlueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTestsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

        $schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
            return new CustomBlueprint($table, $callback);
        });

        $schema->create('tests', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->customColumns();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tests');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I got `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'Database\CustomBlueprint' not found   ` on migration

Comment: Run `composer dumpautoload` then it should be fixed, I am also updating the answer with this fix